# Proof of $b\mid a\iff a\mathbb{Z}\subseteq b\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: divisibility, integers

I have to give a detailed proof of $b\mid a\iff a\mathbb{Z}\subseteq b\mathbb{Z}$. This is from Beachy and Blairs abstract algebra book.

I was thinking like so:

Assume first that $b\mid a$ that is $a=qb$ for some $q\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now we pick an element from $a\mathbb{Z}$ say $an$ we have then
$$
a\mathbb{Z}\ni an=bqn\in b\mathbb{Z}
$$
so each element of $a\mathbb{Z}$ is also an element in $b\mathbb{Z}$ in other words $a\mathbb{Z}\subseteq b\mathbb{Z}$.

For the other implication assume $a\mathbb{Z}\subseteq b\mathbb{Z}$ then
$$
\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}, \ \exists m\in\mathbb{Z} \quad \text{such that}\quad an=bm.
$$
From here I feel that it should not be hard to deduce $b\mid a$ but all I try ends up in a many "cases" and I usually feel that whenever I do more than $2$ cases I don't really grasp something.

Comment: Some small notes; in your first displayed equation, you mean $a\mathbb Z \ni a$ and $bqn \in b\mathbb Z$, subset symbols are not appropriate. Also, I would recommend using a colon in your second displayed equation (or use parentheses) rather than a pipe, since it can be confusing when you're already using that symbol for divisibility.

Comment: Please do not rollback positive edits, especially when those edits are resolving the issues of inappropriate slurs being used on a academic forum

Answer (score 3):

From $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z} \ \exists m\in\mathbb{Z} \mid an=bm$

you get (with $n=1$):

$\exists m_0\in\mathbb{Z} \mid a=bm_0$,

hence $b\mid a$.

Comment: Right! Thank you! I knew I am missing something :)

Comment: Usiing $\,\mid\,$ for both "divides" and "such that".as above surely invites confusion for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a,b\neq 0$ and without loss of generality $a,b \in \mathbf{N}:=\{1,2,\ldots,\}$.

(1) If $b\mid a$ then $a=bn$ for some $n \in \mathbf{N}$, then  $a\mathbf{Z}\subseteq b\mathbf{Z}$.

(2) If $a\mathbf{Z}\subseteq b\mathbf{Z}$ then $a\mathbf{N}\subseteq b\mathbf{N}$ then 
$$
b=\min(b\mathbf{N}) \,\text{ divides }\,\min(a\mathbf{N})=a.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align} {\bf Hint}\quad  
     b\Bbb Z &\supseteq a\Bbb Z\\
\iff\ b\Bbb Z &\supseteq\! \{a\}\\
\iff\ \ \: b \ & \mid\ a
\end{align}
$

**Remark** $ $ that $\ a\Bbb Z\! +\! a'\Bbb Z = \color{#c00}{(a,a')\Bbb Z}\,$ follows similarly

$\ \begin{align} \phantom{\bf Hint}\quad  
     b\Bbb Z &\supseteq a\Bbb Z\! +\! a'\Bbb Z\\
\iff\ b\Bbb Z &\supseteq\! \{a,\ a'\}\\
\iff\ \ \: b \ & \mid\ \ \, a,\ a'\\
\iff \ \ \: b\ & \mid\ (a,\ a')\\
\iff \  b\Bbb Z &\supseteq\! \color{#c00}{(a,a')\Bbb Z}
\end{align}
$